# Does the UnitOfWork pattern add value in an EF application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, tdd, unit-of-work

`EntityFramework` allows me to create tables from `POCO` classes. 
The `Repository pattern` allows me to create an abstraction layer on top of the database concepts, so that I can focus on programming the actual application.

But then, the `UnitOfWork` (UoW) pattern. This is a pattern that is greatly advertised on the Web, especially in combination with EF.

I am using multiple Repositories, and I do have the need of committing stuff in an Atomic fashion. Then I every UoW example, I see that they implement a method `SaveChanges` which does nothing else then pass the call to `DbContext.SaveChanges`. That feels a bit thin so I probably miss the point. Or is the `UnitOfWork` nothing more than a `DbContext` wrapper?

**Example scenario:**

I have a MultiTenant web-application. When a new `Tenant` is created, the user that created the `Tenant` also needs to be stored as user for the newly created `Tenant`. The class that is responsible for creating a new `Tenant` and assign the first `User` in my current case is the `Tenant` class itself. If something fails, neither the `Tenant` nor the `User` should be stored in the database.

The way I handle this now, is that the `DbContext.SaveChanges` is not called before all actions are successfully executed.

Could somebody (preferring an expert in this domain who actually uses UoW in real EF solutions) explain the advantage for using a `UnitOfWork` over relying on the `DbContext`?

Could the expert also tip me on naming conventions? `TenantAndUserUnitOfWork` strikes me as *long* and free for interpretation (not something that you expect in an object oriented world or am I wrong?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the UnitOfWork pattern add value in an EF application?

An unit of work is a good way of representing a domain transaction. So, does it add value to an application using it (either having Entity Framework or any other underlying storage approach)?

**Yes: a good software should implement atomic operations in some scenarios**.

- I need to register an user and create a profile for it.
- I need to remove an order and notice the user that it has been removed.
- ...

Everything could be part of an unit of work.

**Answer: yes, if you want to produce serious software.**

Comment: So I might as well rename UnitOfWork to Transaction? Grouping 2 of more actions into 1 transaction? How would you name the UnitOfWork that registers a new user and creates a new profile for it? RegisterUserAndCreateProfileUnitOfWork? Maybe I have most trouble finding decent names. In all the examples they just call the class UnitOfWork, but that isn't very descriptive in the context... Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @Haxx No no, haha. An unit of work is just that thing of adding, updating or removing and, until you commit, the data isn't persisted. In my opinion, you can understand "Unit of Work" as the object-oriented, domain-level transaction. You don't need a "RegisterUserAndWhateverUnitOfWork": you need an implementation of Unit of Work supporting your domain. If any of your domain objects inherit `DomainObject` (for example), you could create a covariant `IUnitOfWork<out TDomainObject> where TDomainObject : DomainObject` so you can handle any domain object in a very generic way

Comment: @Haxx In fact, I'd suggest you, rather than "RegisterBlahUnitOfWork", an "EFUnitOfWork" implementation of `IUnitOfWork`.

Comment: And you use an EFUnitOfWork as a mediator for different repositories? In other words, EFUnitOfWork is generic, and your repositories are accessed via this UnitOfWork class? Or in MVC4 terms, the Controllers use the EFUnitOfWork to make atomic changes in the Repositories? But the Repositories never ever call SaveChanges themselves.

Comment: @Haxx I do it this way for anything. Not only when using EF, Web and whatever. I honestly believe that this should be the flow: domain changes are handled by Unit of Work, and the Unit of Work talks with the repository. The Unit of Work EF implementation holds a reference to the active DB transaction so, repositories do their work and when the domain transaction ends, this is committed through the UoW.

Comment: Mmmmkay it's getting more clear every comment you post :). At least I learned that I was doing the wrong thing. I am not fully confident that I "get it now". But maybe it will get better reading more with the pointers you gave. Would you know some proper links to continue reading? For some reason the stuff I read so far isn't causing the light bulb to start glowing... :)

Comment: @Haxx Uhmmm... I really don't know links, I've arrived to these points living the experience, you know. Maybe http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html? Sorry, I can't help you on finding a well written tutorial or so about this topic :(

Comment: That's cool. Thanks a lot for all your time. At least I got what I came shopping for: I **do** want to start using UoW :). Thanks again.

Comment: @Haxx Nice!! I feel happy, hahaha, I could convince you! j/k